# Solving a first order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y^2+3y-3yt$? It is not a separable equation. Can we make a substitution so as to make it become separable?

Comment: Have you studied Bernoulli's equation? That seems like the most straightforward way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is as follows. Consider a general equation of the form:

$$x' = f(t) x + g(x,t)$$

Suppose $y' = f(t) y$. Then if $x = y z$ for some $z$, $x' = y' z + y z' = f(t) y z + y z' = f(t) x + y z'$. So the substitution $x = y z$ lets us cancel $f(t) x$ on both sides, obtaining

$$y z' = g(y z,t)$$

In your problem, $f(t) = (3-3t)$ and $g(x,t)=x^2$. So we want to solve the subproblem $y' = (3-3t)y$. You can do this with separation of variables, and the solution is $y=\exp(3t-3/2t^2)$. So it remains to solve

$$\exp(3t - 3/2 t^2)z' = \exp(6t - 3 t^2) z^2$$

or

$$z' = \exp(3t - 3/2 t^2) z^2$$

This may be solved by separation of variables. It should be noted that the solution is not elementary.

Fair warning: I determined that this idea would work by reverse engineering the result from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: thanks for the informative reply